# Вывод List в jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Не удается вывести таблицу в jsp. Данные с базы считываються нормально, пробовал выводить в консоль.
Вот фрагмент сервлета и jsp-файла:

```
else if(request.getParameter("getTransactions") != null) {
        try {
            request.setAttribute("transactionList", DAO.getTransactions("name"));
            request.getRequestDispatcher("transactions.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

transactions.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Transactions</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Transactions</h1>
<table border="1">
    <c:forEach items="${transactionList}" var="tr">
      <tr>
        <td>${tr.value}</td>
        <td>${tr.date}</td>
        <td>${tr.type}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dao.getTransactions() возвращает List.

Comment: так какой результат?

Comment: Пустая таблица.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><c:out value="${tr.date}"/></td>
```

и т.д.

проверьте

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%--@ taglib prefix="sping" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" --%>

<page:template>
<jsp:body>
```

и т.д.

Comment: Пробовал уже. Не помогло.

Comment: проверьте <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%--@ taglib prefix="sping" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" --%>

<page:template>
    <jsp:body>  и т.д.

Comment: Нет, то же самое

Comment: курить на тему WebMvcConfigurerAdapter в Spring Boot или dispatcher-servlet в Spring MVC

Comment: А без спринга никак нельзя?

Comment: Можно в EJB, уточняйте в ваших вопросах свою конфигурацию